# How do I find all text nodes in an XML document with a namespace using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

Suppose I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.com">
    <foo:one>Alpha</foo:one>
    <two foo:Dog="Yorkie">Bravo</two>
    <three>foo:Delta</three>
</root>
```

If I want to use XPath to find all elements that are in the "http://www.foo.com" namespace (such as the element "one"), I can use this:

```
//*[namespace-uri()='http://www.foo.com']
```

If I want to find all elements that have an attribute in that namespace (such as the element "two"), I can use this:

```
//@*[namespace-uri()='http://www.foo.com']
```

If I want to find all elements that have a text node in that namespace (such as the element "three"), what XPath can I use?

XPath 1 or 2 allowed.  Thanks.

Comment: Namespaces apply to nodes (and possibly attributes).  In the text of a text node, there's no concept of a namespace.  It's all just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a namespace on a text node; your `three` node just contains the text `foo:Delta`, which has no special meaning in XML. You can find nodes holding text starting with `foo:` using `starts-with`:

```
//*[starts-with(., "foo:")]
```

Comment: @mindandmedia, I think I answered your question in my original post.  Take a look.

Comment: my bad... just wanted completeness, but didn't read it completely :(

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to find all elements that have a text node in that namespace
>   (such as the element "three"), what XPath can I use?

**Only nodes that have a name can be in a namespace**.

**Thus**: text-nodes, comments and document nodes do not have a (belong to) namespace.

The name of a PI also doesn't belong to any namespace.

Therefore, there is nothing like "a text node in that namespace"...

**In this particular case you can select the wanted elements using this XPath expression**:

```
//*[text()[starts-with(., 'foo:')]]
```

this selects any element in the XML document that has at least one text-node child whose string-value starts with the string `"foo:"`.

Comment: @james.garriss: I am glad my answer was useful to you. Please, consider accepting and/or upvoting it.