# Why does XML Schema allow a QName to be the value of an element?

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, xml-namespaces

In [How do I find all text nodes in an XML document with a namespace using XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382470/), SO users asserted that text nodes in an XML document cannot be namespace qualified.  The [XPath 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Text-Nodes) and [this doc on QNames](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/qnameids.html#sec-qnames-xml) agree with their assertions.

OTOH, consider this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root xmlns:bob="http://www.bob.com">
    <Hello>bob:World</Hello>
</Root>
```

And this XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Hello" type="xs:QName" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It declares `Hello` to be of type `QName`.  If the `http://www.bob.com` namespace is removed from the XML document, it won't validate.

Want to see a real world example that does this?  The [faultcodes in the SOAP 1.2 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part1-20070427/#faultcodes) are one that I've run across.

So here's my questions:

1. Why does XML Schema allow a QName to be the value of an element?  It seems that this contradicts other specs.
2. Is it fair to say that even though XML parsers do not understand a text node to be namespace qualified, other processors, such as schema validators and SOAP processors, do?

Comment: Thank you for asking this question - I seem to be the only other person in the universe who's considered this to be a problem. The issue I have is that XSLT processors don't seem to be able to interpret fault codes as QNames and therefore there's no clean way to convert them between soap 1.1 and soap 1.2 in XSLT.

Comment: You claim that the TAG finding you link to agrees "that text nodes in an XML document cannot be namespace qualified".  But no statement of that form can be found in the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing concepts.

Element and attributes have names, and their names can be namespace-qualified. Text nodes do not have names, so their names obviously cannot be namespace-qualified.

Attributes and text nodes can both have QNames as their content. The namespace prefix in both cases is resolved against the in-scope namespaces of the containing element: that is, all the namespaces declared on the element and its ancestors. This is quite unrelated to the name of the element or attribute in question.

You are correct, however, in pointing out that QNames in element or attribute content cannot be detected by the XML parser itself, only by a schema validator. You are also correct to identify this as a problem. It is not, however, a contradiction between the specs. It's entirely consistent with the fact that an XML parser can't recognize that a node contains a number or a date, but a schema validator can.