# Transform soap 1.1 fault into soap 1.2 fault

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, biztalk

I'm trying to repair some inadequacies in a BizTalk map I've been given which is intended to map a SOAP 1.1 fault into a SOAP 1.2 fault using an associated XSLT stylesheet.

The output does not validate because the SOAP 1.2 schema describes the `<Value>` element as containing an enumeration value which is qualified; for example:

`<Value>prefix:MustUnderstand</Value>` validates;

`<Value>MustUnderstand</Value>` does not;

where `prefix` relates to `xmlns:prefix="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'"`.

The markup which generates this element from the input document is (relevant part only):

```
<xsl:element name="Value">
    <xsl:value-of select="s11:Fault/faultcode/text()"/>
</xsl:element>
```

How can I make XSLT recognise that the enumeration value must be qualified and to supply an appropriate namespace prefix? I've tried `xsl:copy` in the place of value-of which makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the direct answer to my question seems to be "you can't" - [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395254/why-does-xml-schema-allow-a-qname-to-be-the-value-of-an-element#comment25420605_9395254) suggests that XML processors which are not schema-aware simply see text in element simple content, and have no way of distinguishing one string from another. Since XSLT 1.0 is not (very) schema-aware, it seems that expecting it to recognise QNames inside elements is a non-starter.

The workaround I've found is to call a template which strips off anything preceding a ':' character, and concats the prefix of the soap 1.2 envelope namespace in its place.

This sucks, but seems to be the only way to get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you would go about identifying when it does and doesn't need a prefix, but you can determine the prefix to use with

```
name(namespace::*[. = 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'])
```

Or in a more concrete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="soapNs" select="'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Value">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(namespace::*[. = $soapNs]), ':', 
                                   s11:Fault/faultcode)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a handy robustness tweak that I might use to improve the readability of my solution. I didn't know about the `namespace` axis until reading this answer.